# Оптимизация бесконечного цикла

Tags: c++, циклы, оптимизация

Периодически использую бесконечные циклы в отдельных потоках, например, для постоянного мониторинга новых сообщений. 
Естественно, простая запись

```
while(true) {
    test();
}
```

отнимает львиную долю мощности процессора (в моём случае 30%). Для решения этой проблемы я после каждого такта цикла даю ему поспать на пару миллисекунд

```
while(true) {
    test();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(50));
}
```

Благодаря этому нагрузка снижается до ~0.5% при отсутствие новых сообщений, и до ~8% при пиковой нагрузке.

О такой оптимизации, или о любой другой я не нашел информации вообще (плохо искал, да). Слышал только о оптимизации простеньких игр через

```
float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
clock.restart();
time = time/700;
```

и последующим умножением time на скорость игры.

Мой вариант со спячкой меня более чем устраивает, но все равно хочу знать

"**А можно сделать лучше?**"

Comment: Сколько я помню, есть вариант вместо `sleep` писать ` std::this_thread::yield();`, который отдаст выполнение следующему потоку. Как там с производительностью будет - не тестил, просто слышал про возможность.

Comment: Надо смотреть что конкретно выполняется. что такое "новые сообщения". Постараться найти способ спать не заданное время, а до наступления определенного события (т.е. до появления тех самых сообщений, например), для этого могут использоваться select, если дело с сетью или различные виды блокировок, в случае если события рождаются не из сети (функция добавляющая событие включает семафор, по которому просыпается поток)

Comment: Поток должен засыпать и просыпаться только при наличии новых сообщений.. Как это сделать - зависит от того, какие сообщения ожидаются

Comment: А как мне понять, что сообщение пришло, если поток спит? :D Допустим, сейчас один из таких циклов проверяет наличие нового сообщение через сокет `mret = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);`

Comment: С точки зрения самого языка - может и есть какие-то умные решения, которые помогут вам сэкономить ещё какие-нибудь десятые процента нагрузки. Но с точки зрения логики - это правильное решение. Вот как вы проверяете почту? Когда с работы идете, проверяете ящик. И все, дальше ждете сутки и не обращаетесь к ящику. Другое дело - обратные вызовы. Зависит от реализации "прихода сообщений", но в общем случае это похоже на почтальона. Сидите дома, пьёте чай, а он вам звонит в дверь и отдаёт письмо. Вот так

Comment: Раз у вас есть сокет, значит вам надо использовать функцию select (или epoll) им передаешь список сокетов откуда ожидаются сообщения и они останавливают поток до тех пор, пока в одном из перечисленных сокетов не появятся данные. Когда данные появляются, поток просыпается и знает от select в каком именно сокете есть данные, после чего читает только его. таким образом один поток может спокойно обслуживать сотни сокетов и при этом спать все время, пока нет данных

Comment: это наилучший ответ

Answer (score 1):

В много-поточной задаче нормальным является использование объектов синхронизации. В данном контексте вечный цикл не должен выполняться вообще. Поток должен всегда находиться в режиме ожидания. И выполняться только если это позволит объект синхронизации.

Что то вроде этого:

```
  while(true) 
  {
     wait(lock);
     test();
  }
```